# To update R to v4 I deleted v3 but cannot install now

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, r

I had R version 3.. and needed to install v4 to do that first I tried to update R but did not work.
As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118558/complete-remove-and-reinstall-r-including-all-packages) suggests I deleted R packages. When I tried to delete folders which are output of `R -e '.libPaths()` it told there are no such folders.
Then I tried to install R v4 as in the official webpage of R.

```
sudo apt update -qq
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```

And it gave me the output below. Now I do not know what to do can you please help me with that. I am using Ubuntu 16

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.0-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.1.0-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a repository update step missing (`sudo apt-get update`) between adding the repository and attempting to install the package(s)?

Comment: I did that. And now tried again but no result is the same

Comment: OK in that case please [edit] your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy r-base`

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed your apt output shows `4.1.0-1.2004.0` which I believe is the package version for Ubuntu focal - when I followed the above steps (plus the missing update) on a 16.04.07 VM it offers me `4.0.5-1.1604.0`. What is the output of `echo "$(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"`

Comment: it says bionic-cran40/

Comment: So that adds to the confusion - you think the system is "Ubuntu 16" (xenial) - the system thinks it's 18.04 (bionic) and yet we see "2004" (i.e. 20.04 - focal) in the package names. I suspect there's a mix of repositories / sources on your system that needs to be resolved before you can move forward.

Comment: What should I do? How can I search for a solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126279/discussion-between-steeldriver-and-alkanstein).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the issue

- the user believed the OS version to be "Ubuntu 16"
- `lsb_release -cs` returned `bionic` i.e. Ubuntu 18.04
- attempts to install `r-base` suggested the presence of Ubuntu 20.04 (`focal`) respositories

Via comments / chat we discovered that the underlying issue was a mix of different distributions in the user's sources, including the following R specific ones:

```
deb cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/… focal-cran40/ 

deb [arch=i386,amd64] cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/… xenial/ 

deb cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/… bionic-cran40/
```

After commenting out all the non-bionic repositories and re-running `apt update`, the user was able to complete the installation.